# Save value of then in a variable outside of the Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I'm fairly new to the concept of Promises and I'm trying to understand how the scopes work. I'm basically trying to store the value from inside a **then()** into a variable outside of the **Promise**

Below is a simple function I've written in Nodejs (Express), using Sequelize to run the query on the DB.

```
exports.getTest = (req, res, next) => {
    var categories = [];
    var names = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4'];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        model.Category.findOne({
            where: {
                name: names[i]
            },
            attributes: ['id']
        }).then(id => {
            categories.push(
            {
                category_id: id.id
            });
        });
    }
    res.json(categories);
}
```

I have other logic to be run after that, and I have a for loop around the Promise. So, I can't run my next logic inside the then, otherwise I'll have it running multiple times because of the for loop. I need to populate the array **categories** to use it in my next operation.

Currently, my response (`res.json(categories)`) is `[]`

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I know this is a common topic, but as I mentioned, I'm fairly new to this and the other answers didn't fit my scenario and were further confusing me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using async/await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Promise.all()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```js
var getTest = (req, res, next) => {
    var categories = [];
    var promises = [];
    var names = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4'];
    var resolveCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        // Store the name in variable so that can be persistent and not
        // affected by the changing 'i' value
        const name = names[i]
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
          // Your DB calls here. We shall use a simple timer to mimic the
          // effect
          setTimeout(() => {
            categories.push(name)
            resolveCount++;
            resolve();
          }, 1000)
        }));
    }
    
    
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      console.log("This should run ONCE before AFTER promise resolved")
      console.log("resolveCount: " + resolveCount)
      console.log(categories);
      
      // Do your logic with the updated array
      // res.json(categories);
    });
    
    console.log("This will run immediately, before any promise resolve")
    console.log("resolveCount: " + resolveCount)
    console.log(categories)
}

getTest();
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly. So did Isaac's solution. However, you have encapsulated the DB calls into another Promise `new Promise((resolve, reject)`. And in Isaac's solution, I'm directly adding the DB calls (Promises) into the promises array. What difference does it make? The results are the exact same, though.

Comment: The function model.Category.findOne(..).then() returns a Promise, so you can just push the result of this function into the array. For my example though, I've created multiple new Promise to illustrate the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `categories` will always return `[]` because you aren't waiting for all your promises to finish before returning your response. For loops do not wait for asynchronous actions to complete before continuing on to the next iteration. Therefore the loop ends, and a response is returned before any of them finish.

Instead of calling promises within a for loop, you should push them to an array, which you can then pass to `Promise.all()` function.

Here is what it should look like

```
exports.getTest = () => {
    var categories = [];
    var names = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4'];
    var promiseArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(
          model.Category.findOne({
              where: {
                  name: names[i]
              },
              attributes: ['id']
          }).then(id => {
              categories.push(
              {
                  category_id: id.id
              });
          });
        )
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseArr)
}
```

`getTest()` now returns a promise, so it can be called like this

```
getTest()
  .then(data => {
    // data will be an array of promise responses
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. This is working perfectly fine. While your answer was to the point, Jimmy's answer helped me understand the concept and the flow behind it. With that understanding, I was able to then modify the code to suit my requirements. But thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
exports.getTest = (req, res, next) => {
    var categories = [];
    var names = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4'];
    names.forEach(name => {
        Category.findOne({where: {name: name}}).then(category => {
            categories.push({category_id: category.id})
        })
    })
    res.json(categories);
}
```

So basically, model.findeOne() returns a promise with the object of the first category with each of the names. then() catches that promise, resolves it and you give it a callback function that get that object passed as a parameter.

It could look something like

```
Categories.findOne({where: {name: name}).then(function(category){
    // do something with that category
})
```

But the arrow function makes it a lot more readable as then(category => {//some
code}).

Comment: ForEach can be used pretty much the same way, where instead of writing `categories.forEach(function(category){ //do something })`, we use arrow function and every category in that array will be passed as an argument to your functon

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all, its pretty much the exact same code OP has, except instead of using a for loop you're using `.forEach`